# what does this error mean "Script did not clean its stack" while signing segwit transactions

Tags: bitcoin-cash, segregated-witness, createrawtransaction

I'm trying to sign raw transaction on Bitcoin fork (Bitcoin-ABC 0.16.2) but I get `Script did not clean its stack`

```
        [args] => Array
            (
                [RAW] => 0200000001455f65335121517a3cd72737bd6d49dd0523dacc68465cac514dd723624f92f40000000000ffffffff0280c3c901000000001976a91409fed3e08e624b23dbbacc77f7b2a39998351a6888ac80bbaf4b000000001976a914c1f41b20bb5a64080f19347fb03f1cafbb19793e88ac00000000
                [PRVKEY] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => cPsVieHs6F5UBcWjG7Sp12bEjC6Jn6Qnbdj8CsrPDH1cCF6sdqiU
                    )

                [INPUTS] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [txid] => f4924f6223d74d51ac5c4668ccda2305dd496dbd3727d73c7a51215133655f45
                                [vout] => 0
                                [scriptPubKey] => a9140ef96a27286c7ce607623cf4f8ca4ba2ec977b2c87
                                [amount] => 13.000000
                                [address] => 2MtcQEbyzHoELWmzeMonsfbbLpBsTdU8BbD
                                [redeemScript] => 00143b7ec6d6e7697ed406f3bb825e028238ab5cc623
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, Bitcoin cash doesn't support segwit.